# No line between points in Gmap.Net route

Tags: c#, winforms, gmap.net

I'm using Gmap.Net on windows form, I want to draw track of an object when I receive its position, I use `Routes` for this. When I add points to a route, no line is seen on the map, but when I change the zoom of the map, they appear on the map. Also when I set the position of the map after adding a point to the route (`gMapControl1.Position = new PointLatLng(...)`), it works correctly and I see the route lines on the map, any idea? My code is like below.

```
void NewDataReceived(DeviceInfo deviceinf)
{
    //---some codes
    //----For the first time I add layer and route 
    if (deviceOverLay == null)
    {
        deviceOverLay = new GMapOverlay(deviceinf.DeviceId.ToString());
        gMapControl1.Overlays.Add(deviceOverLay);
        deviceRoute = new GMapRoute(new List<PointLatLng>(), deviceinf.DeviceName);
        deviceOverLay.Routes.Add(deviceRoute);
        //Add all your points here
        deviceRoute.Points.Add(new PointLatLng(deviceinf.Latitude, deviceinf.Longitude));
        deviceRoute.Tag = deviceinf;
    }
    else
    {
        deviceOverLay.Routes[0].Points.Add(new PointLatLng(deviceinf.Latitude, deviceinf.Longitude));
    }

    //if I call this line it works, but I don't want it
    // gMapControl1.Position = new PointLatLng(deviceinf.Latitude, deviceinf.Longitude);  
    //---some codes
}
```

Comment: I've never used GMap.Net, but it looks like updating a Route doesn't immediately invalidate the map control, while directly adding a point to the map control does.  Makes sense, since I might want to build a whole route before drawing it.  Try gMapControl.Invalidate() or something similar.  The fact that it shows up when you change the zoom means the point has been added.

Comment: Thanks "cdkMoose", I tried gMapControl.Invalidate(), but it didn't solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using

```
gMapControl1.UpdateRouteLocalPosition(deviceRoute);
```

This updates the local positions and does a redraw.

Comment: Thank  you very much @JAlecksen, you almost solved the problem. with calling UpdateRouteLocalPosition method, even with clicking on the map I can saw the route lines, previously only with changing zoom or calling other zooming method I could see the route line. Finally if we call "gMapControl.Invalidate()" before the method you mentioned it works correctle, thanks again. I will also mention your answer in this link:[link](https://greatmaps.codeplex.com/discussions/658235). Thanks again.